# How to use skimage.measure.regionprops to query labels

Tags: python, scikit-image

Can someone help me out with [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops)? The documentation was confusing to me in describing the list of properties that `regionprops` provides.

I would like to do the following:

- Query a point (x,y) and return which labeled area the point belongs in.
- Get an ndarray of all points within a labeled area.

---

Here is some code showing what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

img = label(arr)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Examples of what I want to do are making a query to `arr[8][6]` and knowing which label it is a part of (green) and to know all of the points that belong to an arbitrary label (like green).

Answer (score 3):

The numeric label of any pixel can be retrieved by indexing `img`:

```
In [67]: row, col = 8, 6

In [68]: index = img[row, col]

In [69]: print(f'The label of pixel [{row}, {col}] is {index}')
The label of pixel [8, 6] is 2
```

The you could use NumPy's [`nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to get the coordinates of all the pixels with the same label:

```
In [70]: coords = np.nonzero(img == index)

In [71]: coords
Out[71]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8], dtype=int32),
 array([6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int32))

In [72]: out = np.zeros(shape = arr.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)

In [73]: out[coords] = [0, 255, 0]    # green

In [74]: plt.imshow(out)
Out[74]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x11a2ec10>
```

[image: green region]